# How to Make Mockito Verification of Varargs Match Actual Invocation?

Tags: java, testing, mockito, datadog

I recently upgraded from mockito-core version 1.10.19 to the latest version(5.5.0). I've noticed a change in behavior when verifying a method call with a varargs parameter.

In the older version, I used a custom matcher with the following signature:

```
private class CustomMatcher<T> extends ArgumentMatcher<T[]> implements VarargMatcher
```

However, in the latest version, due to changes in ArgumentMatcher, I had to modify the signature to:

```
private class CustomMatcher<T> implements ArgumentMatcher<T[]>, Serializable
```

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
package com.mockito.varargs.test;

import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*;

public class TestHelper {

    private final DummyClient client = Mockito.mock(DummyClient.class);

    public TestHelper() {
    }

    public void execute(String... tags) {
        client.record("action", 42L, tags);
        client.histogram("someAspect", 100L, "type:total", "type:cpu", "type:wait", "type:sql");
        new Verifier().verifyTagsAre("tag1", "tag2", "tag3");
    }

    public class Verifier {
        public void verifyTagsAre(final String... expectedTags) {
            Mockito.verify(client).record(eq("action"), eq(42L),
                    argThat(new CustomMatcher<>(expectedTags)));
            Mockito.verify(client, Mockito.times(3)).histogram(eq("someAspect"), anyLong(),
                    argThat(new CustomAnyVarargMatcher<>(
                            new CustomMatcher<>("type:total", expectedTags),
                            new CustomMatcher<>("type:cpu", expectedTags),
                            new CustomMatcher<>("type:wait", expectedTags),
                            new CustomMatcher<>("type:sql", expectedTags)
                    )));
            Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(client);
        }
    }

    private class CustomMatcher<T> implements ArgumentMatcher<T[]>, Serializable {
        private T[] expectedValues;

        CustomMatcher(T... expectedValues) {
            this.expectedValues = expectedValues;
        }

        CustomMatcher(T t, T... expectedValues) {
            T[] values = (T[]) Array.newInstance(t.getClass(), expectedValues.length + 1);
            System.arraycopy(expectedValues, 0, values, 1, expectedValues.length);
            values[0] = t;
            this.expectedValues = values;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(T[] args) {
            return Arrays.equals(expectedValues, args);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Arrays.toString(expectedValues);
        }
    }

    private class CustomAnyVarargMatcher<T> implements ArgumentMatcher<T>, Serializable {
        private ArgumentMatcher<T>[] matchers;

        CustomAnyVarargMatcher(ArgumentMatcher<T>... matchers) {
            this.matchers = matchers;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(T args) {
            for (ArgumentMatcher<T> matcher : matchers) {
                if (matcher.matches(args))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Arrays.toString(matchers);
        }
    }

    interface DummyClient {
        void record(String action, long value, String... tags);
        void histogram(String aspect, long value, String... tags);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestHelper().execute("tag1", "tag2", "tag3");
    }
}
```

When the verification fails, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
dummyClient.record(
    "action",
    42L,
    [tag1, tag2, tag3]
);
-> at com.mockito.varargs.test.TestHelper$Verifier.verifyTagsAre(TestHelper.java:26)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
dummyClient.record(
    "action",
    42L,
    "tag1",
    "tag2",
    "tag3"
);
```

I was expecting the expected output to match the actual invocation, as it did in version 1.10.19. Is there a way to achieve this in the latest version? Or is there a way to compare the varargs as arrays in Mockito, so that the verification passes if the arrays are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `AdditionalMatchers`, no need for a custom matcher:

```
public void verifyTagsAre(final String... expectedTags) {
    Mockito.verify(client).record(eq("action"), eq(42L),
            AdditionalMatchers.aryEq(expectedTags));
    Mockito.verify(client, Mockito.times(3)).histogram(eq("someAspect"), anyLong(), AdditionalMatchers.aryEq(new String[] { "type:total", "type:cpu", "type:wait", "type:sql" }));
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(client);
}
```

See GitHub issues [mockito#1593](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1593) and [mockito#2835](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/pull/2835), especially the bit about `argThat`:

> `argThat()` behaviour change
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: The behaviour of all methods in `MockitoHamcrest`, such as `argThat()`, when passed to a varargs parameter has changed. Prior to Mockito v5, these matchers would match each element in the varargs parameter, matching any number of elements 0...n. From Mockito v5 onwards these matchers, when passed to a varargs parameter, will match invocations where a single value is passed to the varargs parameter. To match any number of values passed to the varargs parameter, pass use suitable Hamcrest Matcher and the varargs array type to `argThat`. For example, given a `String...` varargs parameter, use: `argThat(isA(String[].class), String[].class)`.

And I hope the code is only an example for the question, because there is no real code being tested. You have a Mockito mock object, on which you call methods, then verify that the method has been called. I'm not even sure that the test has ever worked – the `histogram` method is called only once, but the verifier checks `times(3)` (with argument types that do not actually match: `expectedTags` are never passed to `histogram`).

Comment: The code is an example (times(3) is something I forgot while converting to dummy test), when I tried ```AdditionalMatchers.aryEq(expectedTags)``` it is still trying with wanted 
dummyClient.record(
    "action",
    42L,
    [tag1, tag2, tag3]
);    thank you for issue links and I am going with Mockito.verify(client).record(eq("action"), eq(42L), any(String[].class)); for now

Comment: @soso maybe try `argThat(aryEq(new String[] { "type:total", "type:cpu", ... }), String[].class)` – that might help. If it does, I will update my answer

Comment: no, this did not help